Derivation of the minima for diffraction through a single slit
I need a detailed answer of the question
Classical derivation of first and second minima in Single slit diffraction
My questions are
First why for 1st minima we divide the length a into 2 parts and why into 4 parts for 2nd minima and so on
My second question is that for destructive interference why are we taking the path difference to be $\lambda/2$ be it 1st or 2nd minima why not $(2n-1)\lambda/2$ for n being a natural number
I've searched a lot over the internet it's been more than 1hr 20 min and I'm unable to find an explanation from myself please help me I'm extremely confused regarding this.
Thankyou.

Is there some problem with question? That I'm getting no answers?
